# Why does PDFDomTree embed erroneous base64 of font types?

Tags: java, html, css, fonts

When I convert PDF to HTML format using below code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("./pdf_test_file.pdf");
            File outputPath = new File("./pdf.html");

            PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(file);
            Writer output = new PrintWriter(outputPath, "utf-8");
            new PDFDomTree().writeText(pdf, output);

            output.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get correct formatting of html representing the pdf file BUT the problem is that it PDFDomTree embeds images the right way using base64 but some how I get following errors in console of the generated HTML:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix these console errors? Because of them I also get overlapping text as the browser can't find out what the font type is of the text.

**MY GRADLE BUILD DEPENDENCIES:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.24.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.24.1'
    implementation 'net.sf.cssbox:pdf2dom:1.9'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation  'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.19'

    implementation 'fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core:1.0.5'
    implementation 'fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml:1.0.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.17'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

**GENERATED HTML FROM PDF USING CODE ABOVE**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
        <title>PDF Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family:"BCDEEE Algerian";src:url('data:application/x-font-truetype;base64,AAEAAAAMAIAAAwBAT1MvMny ... some more base64 ... IUdEwA/Pz8/AQ==');}
@font-face {font-family:"BCDFEE Calibri-Italic";src:url('data:application/x-font-truetype;base64,AAEAAAAQAIAAAwCARUJEVJyXnKAAA ... some more base64 ... KysrKysrKysrKysYX14AAAA=');}
@font-face {font-family:"BCDGEE Calibri";src:url('data:application/x-font-truetype;base64,AAEAAAAQAIAAAwCARUJEVArzURQAAAEMAAAHPkVCTEMq+L ... some more base64 ... KysrKysrKwBzc3Nzc3N0KysrKysrKysrKxhfXgA=');}

.page{position:relative; border:1px solid blue;margin:0.5em}
.p,.r{position:absolute;}
@supports(-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black) {.p{text-shadow:none !important;}}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page" id="page_0" style="width:595.32pt;height:841.92pt;overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="p" id="p0" style="top:80.0213pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:58.653854pt;font-family:BCDEEE Algerian;font-size:50.0pt;color:#ff0000;width:245.34612pt;">Algerian</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:72.024pt;top:132.73999pt;width:375.43pt;height:2.880005pt;background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p1" style="top:80.0213pt;left:329.67996pt;line-height:58.653854pt;font-family:BCDEEE Algerian;font-size:50.0pt;color:#ff0000;width:117.84421pt;">font</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:72.024pt;top:203.89996pt;width:121.7pt;height:2.880005pt;background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p2" style="top:151.18127pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:58.653854pt;font-family:BCDEEE Algerian;font-size:50.0pt;color:#ff0000;width:121.79736pt;">type</div>
            <div class="p" id="p3" style="top:232.63998pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:90.77257pt;">THIS</div>
            <div class="p" id="p4" style="top:232.63998pt;left:174.1056pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:35.228165pt;">IS</div>
            <div class="p" id="p5" style="top:232.63998pt;left:220.6428pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:28.97316pt;">A</div>
            <div class="p" id="p6" style="top:232.63998pt;left:260.92502pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:95.626434pt;">TEST</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:72.024pt;top:275.81pt;width:427.03003pt;height:3.2399902pt;background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p7" style="top:232.63998pt;left:367.8605pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:131.20483pt;">USING</div>
            <div class="p" id="p8" style="top:298.4pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:155.72447pt;">CALIBRI</div>
            <div class="p" id="p9" style="top:298.4pt;left:239.05751pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:91.87343pt;">AND</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:72.024pt;top:341.57pt;width:382.63pt;height:3.2399902pt;background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p10" style="top:298.4pt;left:342.31pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:112.33978pt;">FONT</div>
            <div class="p" id="p11" style="top:364.28pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:83.06641pt;">SIZE</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:72.024pt;top:407.44998pt;width:144.98pt;height:3.2399902pt;background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p12" style="top:364.28pt;left:166.39944pt;line-height:50.04001pt;font-family:BCDFEE Calibri-Italic;font-size:50.0pt;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;width:50.74057pt;">50</div>
            <div class="p" id="p13" style="top:506.94998pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;color:#a9d18e;width:35.79264pt;">TES</div>
            <div class="p" id="p14" style="top:506.94998pt;left:107.9pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:12.155518pt;">T</div>
            <div class="r" style="left:125.64pt;top:519.36pt;width:168.59999pt;height:1.6799927pt;background-color:#a8d08d;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p" id="p15" style="top:506.94998pt;left:125.66pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:168.47998pt;">TTTTTEEESSSTTT</div>
            <div class="p" id="p16" style="top:588.892pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:24.983948pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:12.966698pt;">X</div>
            <div class="p" id="p17" style="top:586.66003pt;left:84.984pt;line-height:15.959961pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:15.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:8.091721pt;">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page_1" style="width:595.32pt;height:841.92pt;overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="p" id="p18" style="top:240.72195pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:24.984009pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:73.330795pt;">Testing</div>
            <div class="p" id="p19" style="top:240.72195pt;left:150.98pt;line-height:24.984009pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:58.5625pt;">green</div>
            <div class="p" id="p20" style="top:240.72195pt;left:215.18887pt;line-height:24.984009pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#a9d18e;width:51.367126pt;">color</div>
            <div class="p" id="p21" style="top:281.80997pt;left:72.024pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#4471c4;width:73.272pt;">Testing</div>
            <div class="p" id="p22" style="top:281.80997pt;left:150.98pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#4471c4;width:44.553604pt;">blue</div>
            <div class="p" id="p23" style="top:281.80997pt;left:201.29pt;line-height:24.959991pt;font-family:BCDGEE Calibri;font-size:24.0pt;letter-spacing:-0.0355pt;color:#4471c4;width:51.417587pt;">color</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PDFBox is not to blame here. The HTML is created by PDFDomTree.

Comment: Hallo @TilmanHausherr I added my gradle dependencies to the question.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, then you'd need to create an issue in the PDFDomTree project.